# Write BOOL value to plist from a button

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, plist

**Background**

I have 2 tableViews, the first one is the Main table and the second one is the Favorites table.

Everything is handled with a plist.

From the detailView of the first table, in the upper-corner I set up a button to write to the plist the value YES.

The plist is structured this way:

```
Section 1                  Dictionary
      Title                String
      Rows                 Array 
        Item 0             Dictionary
           name            String
           description     String
           image           String
           isFav           Bool (default NO)
      Item 1               Dictionary
           name            String
           description     String
           image           String
           isFav           Bool (default NO)

Section 2
      Title
      Rows
        Item 0             Dictionary
           name            String
           description     String
           image           String
           isFav           Bool (default NO)
        etc..
```

Adding a little scheme of how it should work:

```
firstTable          detailView                          plist
 __________          ________                   
|          |        |     |★ |<- button pressed ---> cellname isFav = YES      
|__________|        |        |               
|cellname  | ------>| detail |    
|__________|        |        |               
|          |        |        |               
|          |        |        |
```

**The problem**

Now that I have that button, I was trying to write a method to write the isFav bool value to the plist.

`-(void)makeFavorite`

I already had a method to read the plist, but I don't know how to write a value on it.
I tried to search on google and read other stackOverflow posts but I can't really figure it out.
Any help appreciated!

**EDIT**

This is the method do read the plist

```
- (NSArray*)readPlist 
{ 
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *plistPath = [[documentPaths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tipsList.plist"]; 

    NSFileManager *fMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
    if (![fMgr fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) { 
        plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tipsList" ofType:@"plist"]; 

    } 
    return [NSArray dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
}
```

And in the method I was typing:

```
- (void) makeFavorite:(id)sender
 {   
     NSArray *test = [self readPlist];
     NSLog (@"test: %@",test);
    //write plist instructions then
 }
```

Comment: Shouldn't your plist be returning a dictionary when you read it?

Comment: @JamesWebster no, as you see it is an array of dictionaries. Section 1 and 2 are dictionaries but they are both in a top-level array object ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass the `indexPath` from your `tableView` to your `detailView`. Create a

```
@property (copy) NSIndexPath *indexPath;
```

in your `detailView` and assign it with

```
detailView.indexPath = indexPath; // the one from the current selected cell
```

Then you can create a favorite method like this one:

```
- (IBAction)makeFavorite 
{ 
    NSArray *plist = [self readPlist]; 
    NSDictionary *theItem = [[[plist objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"Rows"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // get the current state 
    BOOL fav = [[theItem valueForKey:@"isFav"] boolValue]; 
    // set the opposite of the current value 
    [theItem setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!fav] forKey:@"isFav"]; 

    [self writePlist:plist]; 

    // update the UI, set new image or something
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:(!fav ? @"FullStar.png" : @"EmptyStar.png")];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for:

```
[myDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"isFav"]
```

Comment: Kind of. How should it be implemented in the makeFavorite method? 
In that method i already have something to read the plist but not to write :\

Comment: Can you show us the piece of code you use to read the plist so I can use your variable names etc

Comment: Shouldn't your plist be returning a dictionary?

Comment: It returns an array that's assigned to another array (i'm working with local and remote plist, a bit tricky). But if should be returning a dictionary in that view i will transform it as dictionary

Comment: Try using `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithFile:]` and returning an NSDictionary then print it with an NSLog and you should understand the structure a bit better.

Comment: hmm seems like it's null. I returned the NSDictionary and then in the method i wrote `NSDictionary *test = [self readPlist]`and logged it, but the result it's null

Comment: I don't understand how your code was working with an array, but not a dictionary. How are you using the array after you read it?

Comment: You mean in other methods? 
Well after reading it, in the firstTable, i load the table with the contents of that array (localPlist). 
Then, from a button, i check for updates at the plist and i download them and write to the local plist.

Answer (score 2):

An outline, none of the steps is particularly involved:

First you need a *mutable* dictionary if you intended to change it. Reading a plist with `ditionaryWithContentsOfFile:` produces an immutable one if you call this for `NSDictionary` (obviously).

If you call the same method on `NSMutableDictionary` the documentation suggests the dictionary itself is mutable, but the objects it contains are not. In your case you wish to change a single value in a dictionary embedded in an array, itself embedded in a dictionary (at least) - i.e. you need mutable objects.

There are other methods to read in a plist which let you specify that you need mutable objects, start with the first section of [Reading and Writing Property List data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/ReadWritePlistData/ReadWritePlistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH8-SW1).

Second, once you have your mutable plist changing it is just down to calling `setObject:forKey:` on the appropriate sub-dictionary - so from the outer dictionary you obtain the array, from the array you obtain the inner dictionary, and then you set the object for the key.

Finally you need to write it out. For that write a complement to your `readPlist` which uses methods such as `writeToFile:atomically:` of `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, i'll try to figure out something

Answer (score 2):

**Write Bool Value in NSUserDefault In iOS**

```
write 
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"instructionCheck"];


Get
Bool flag=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"instructionCheck"];
```